# Spring factory-bean with property resolution

Tags: spring

Is it possible to have property resolution on the factory-bean field of a Spring bean declaration?

Example:

```
<bean factory-bean="$APP{some.factory.bean}" factory-method="...">
```

Spring version: 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Adding a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) to your spring context should work:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:yourfile.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

You can declare your `propertyName` in the file and then use it like:

```
<bean factory-bean="${propertyName}" factory-method="...">
```

Comment: I've changed the latest Spring's PetClinic example in order to test this but I'm still getting `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '$APP{some.factory.bean}' is defined`. You can check my changes [here](https://github.com/andredasilvapinto/spring-petclinic/commit/876e373574805929fa441507b887a098861d3ebf).

Comment: @andresp: if you inject that property into some other bean's value does it get resolved? Is the config.properties a new file? If yes, did you redeploy after adding it?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes.
The resolution only fails when it is used for the name of the bean itself. My hypothesis is that Spring only does property resolution after creating the beans, so this feature is not available at this stage.
Updated code [here](https://github.com/andredasilvapinto/spring-petclinic/commit/e2a1d03ad0909c7ef1cbcfcfc4986325515185b8).

Comment: @andresp: Spring first creates the bean definitions, replaces the placeholder values in the bean definitions and only then creates the beans. Maybe in this case it's limited because that's a dependency instead of a value and those might be resolved first?!

Comment: Sorry, it is obviously not "after creating the beans" (as that would imply constructors would be called still with the placeholders), what I wanted to say was "after creating its internal representation of the beans".

I suppose that, as factory-beans create new beans themselves, the property resolution will only happen after the factory-methods are called (so we have the complete list the start up beans available). 

In order to call those methods, Spring needs to know the bean name, therefore the creation fails as it still doesn't know which factory-bean the definition is referring to.

Comment: Obviously, when using properties for bean classes or parent beans it works fine.
I'm not sure if I should report this as a bug, or not...

Comment: @andresp: not sure if this is a bug, it does make some sense to behave like that, maybe raise an issue with a question? Alternatively this can be achieved by having a discriminator value injected into the factory bean itself and have the factory bean decide after what other beans to go to resolve the value based on the discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue (using Spring 4.2.0). It seems that property resolution for factory beans does not work despite what they say in [SPR-12638](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12638). I've ended up using `ProxyFactoryBean` as a workaround.

The desired configuration, which does not work:

```
<!-- The bean to be created: factory type determined in runtime -->
<bean id="..." factory-bean="factory-${factory.type}" factory-method="..." />

<!-- Possible factories -->
<bean id="factory-A" class="..." />
<bean id="factory-B" class="..." />
<bean id="factory-C" class="..." />
```

The workaround that I've found:

```
<!-- The bean to be created: use factory proxy -->
<bean id="..." factory-bean="factory-proxy" factory-method="..." />

<!-- The factory proxy: real factory type determined in runtime -->
<bean id="factory-proxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="factory-${factory-type}" />
</bean>

<!-- Possible factories -->
<bean id="factory-A" class="..." />
<bean id="factory-B" class="..." />
<bean id="factory-C" class="..." />
```

Enjoy :)